# How to solve this logarithmic equation for x

Tags: logarithms

How can the following equation solved for x?

$\ln(x) - \ln(1-x) = \ln(1-y) - \ln(1-z) - \ln(v)$

I assume it simplifies to:

$\frac{x}{1-x} = \frac{1-y}{(1-z)*v} $

I have tried to solve this by factorizing the terms, but it does not lead anywhere. Any hints?

Comment: Write the LHS as $\frac{(x-1)+1}{1-x}$ and split it into two fractions. The $x$ only appears once so you can solve for it.

Comment: Ah indeed I did not know this trick. Thanks.

Comment: Put $RHS=a$ so you have $x=\dfrac{a}{1+a}$ Then simplify.

Comment: @Piquito I do not understand how you can set x equal to $\frac{a}{1+a}$. Could you elaborate a bit?

Comment: Hi EtoAls: Actually it is the same that $\frac{x}{1-x}=a$ but I rather put its equivalent to help you a bit. You have $$\frac{x}{1-x}=a\iff x=a-ax\iff x(1+a)=a$$

Comment: I see that makes it clear, ty!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

\begin{align*}
\frac{x}{1-x} &= \frac{x\overbrace{-1+1}^{0}}{1-x}  \\
    &= \frac{x-1}{1-x} + \frac{1}{1-x}  \\
    &= -1 + \frac{1}{1-x}  
\end{align*}
So you have
\begin{align*}
-1 + \frac{1}{1-x} &= \frac{1-y}{(1-z)v}  \\
\frac{1}{1-x} &= 1 + \frac{1-y}{(1-z)v}  \\
\frac{1-x}{1} &= \frac{1}{1 + \frac{1-y}{(1-z)v}  }  \\
x-1 &= \frac{-1}{1 + \frac{1-y}{(1-z)v}  }  \\
x &= 1 + \frac{-1}{1 + \frac{1-y}{(1-z)v}  }  \\
\end{align*}

Notice that your original equation has the constraints $x > 0$, $1-x > 0$, $1-y > 0$, $1-z > 0$, and $v > 0$.  The above introduces the constraint $1 + \frac{1-y}{(1-z)v} \neq 0$ (although this follows as a consequence of the others).

Answer (score 0):

$$\frac{x}{1-x} = \frac{1-y}{(1-z)v} \implies \frac{x}{1-y}=\frac{1-x}{(1-z)v} = \frac{x+1-x}{1-y+(1-z)v}=\frac{1}{1-y+(1-z)v}\\
\implies x = \frac{1-y}{1-y+(1-z)v}$$

where we used the fact that if $\frac ab = \frac cd$ then
$$\frac ab = \frac cd = \frac{a+c}{b+d}\tag1$$

Comment: Thank you very much, that looks a bit shorter than the below solution (although I assume they are equivalent)

Comment: (1) is a very useful trick. Glad you liked it

Comment: I would accept both solutions if I could. I also cannot upvote u unfortunately because of low rep.

Comment: No worries.  I'm not rep-seeking.